# HTTP request to search for multiple ObjectIds in a Mongo-based API?

Tags: mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I'm looking to add search functionality to an API, on a resource called **Organizations**. **Organizations** can have different **Location** and **Audience** ids tagged onto them (which I would like to use in searching). Since these ids are MongoDB ObjectIds, they are quite long and I'm worried about reaching the max query string limit of the browser with a GET request. For example:

```
GET http://my-site.com/api/organizations?locations=5afa54e5516c5b57c0d43227,5afa54e5516c5b57c0d43226,5afa54e5516c5b57c0d43225,5afa54e5516c5b57c0d43224&audiences=5afa54e5516c5b57c0d43223,5afa54e5516c5b57c0d43222
```

Which would probably be about an average search, however I don't want it to break if users select many **Locations** or **Audiences**.

Any advice on how I could handle this situation?

Comment: Put the list in the "body" of a different request type instead of GET? It's not really clear based on the question content what you really want to do, but typically instead of sending a "list" you probably should be looking at storing a common "singular" Id value which will be shared amongst what you actually get to retrieve. Better to give content on what you need to achieve than ask what is essentially a very broad question.

Comment: Looks to me like there is no serious limit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ran into your situation before. You can change your method to `POST`

For a input of `locations` and `audiences`, your resource is not already sitting there. You have to compute it.

[By the definition of `POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3):

> Perform resource-specific processing on the   request payload.

> Providing a block of data, such as the fields entered into an HTML
> form, to a data-handling process;

You have to compute and create new resource for response. So it's REST-compliance to do so.